# How to access data inside a modal using Vue js?

Tags: vue.js

I'm editing a candidate_profile with a relationship with the Users table. I was able to access the User Object within the candidate_profile and display it, but I just want to display the name property.

Here is a screenshot of the User object in the textarea field. How can I do this?
[image]

Here is my data:

```
data() {
            return {
                candidateProfiles: {
                    user: ''
                },
                editCandidateProfileData: {},
                }
            };
        },
```

Here is my button which calls the editProfile function:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success"
v-on:click="editProfile(candidateProfile)">Request an Interview</button>
```

```
editProfile(candidateProfile) {
                this.editCandidateProfileData = {...candidateProfile};
                this.showInterviewRequestModal();
            },
```

Finally, inside my modal I can get the User object like this:

```
<b-form-group label="Name" label-for="name">
                    <b-form-textarea
                        id="experience"
                        v-model="editCandidateProfileData.user"
                        placeholder="Tell us a little about your experience..."
                        :rows="10"
                        :max-rows="12"
                    >
                    </b-form-textarea>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.user">{{ errors.user[0] }}</div>
                </b-form-group>
```

Comment: You should just be able to access the property off of the object: `editCandidateProfileData.user.name`

Comment: That's what I tried but my page becomes empty and I get this error:
```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Comment: Add v-if="editCandidateProfileData.user"